# Idea is correct, proof lacks rigor, coefficient of $t$ in $\det(I+tA)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, determinant, trace

The goal of this exercise is to find the coefficient of $t$ in the polynomial $\det(I+tA)$ where $I, A \in Mat_n(\mathbb R)$.

I've thought about this long and hard as I am combinatorically challenged (it's the most difficult branch of mathematics for certain) and I'm pretty sure I have a convincing argument, but it feels handwavey and lacks rigor. I'd like someone to review it and possibly suggest way to make it less verbal and more rigorous.

My argument uses Laplace expansion, initially using the first **column** of $I+tA$.

$\det(I+tA) = (1+ta_{1,1})\begin{vmatrix}1+ta_{2,2} & ta_{2,3} & \dots & ta_{2,n}\\ta_{3,2} & 1+ta_{3, 3} & \dots & ta_{3,n}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots \\ ta_{n, 2} & ta_{n, 3} & \dots & 1+ta_{n,n}\end{vmatrix} -ta_{2,1}\det(B_2) + ta_{3,1}\det(B_3)-\dots+(-1)^{n+1}ta_{n, 1}\det(B_n)$

Where $B_i$ are some sub matrices with accordance to Laplace.

Notice that since we used the first column in our original expansion, the first row of every $B_i$ is just $\begin{pmatrix}ta_{1,2} \dots ta_{1,n}\end{pmatrix} = t\begin{pmatrix}a_{1,2} \dots a_{1,n}\end{pmatrix} $

if we define $B_i'$ to be exactly the same as $B_i$ **except the first row** is divided by $t$, then by determinant rules $\det(B_i) = t\det(B_i')$, and so:

$-ta_{2,1}\det(B_2) + ta_{3,1}\det(B_3)-\dots+(-1)^{n+1}ta_{n, 1}\det(B_n) = -t^2a_{2,1}\det(B_2') + t^2a_{3,1}\det(B_3')-\dots+(-1)^{n+1}t^2a_{n, 1}\det(B_n')$

and they only contain non linear terms of $t$. So they don't matter to us at all. We can just focus on the first determinant.

But now we can just use the exact same argument on $\begin{vmatrix}1+ta_{2,2} & ta_{2,3} & \dots & ta_{2,n}\\ta_{3,2} & 1+ta_{3, 3} & \dots & ta_{3,n}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots \\ ta_{n, 2} & ta_{n, 3} & \dots & 1+ta_{n,n}\end{vmatrix}$! The only thing that will matter is the first element and its leading minor. The others can be discarded as they are higher order of $t$.

We will use it again and again until at the end we are only left with $\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+ta_{i,i})$. The answer is hidden somewhere in this product.

Since we are only interested in linear terms, we are not allowed to multiply $ta_{i,i}$ with $ta_{j,j}$. So every $ta_{i,i}$ can only be multiplied by $1$. So overall we should have $ta_{1,1} + ta_{2,2} + \dots ta_{n,n} = tTrace(A)$.

Is this result correct? is this "proof" valid? It feels too wishy washy and verbal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result is correct. I think your argument is fine, although it is not very amenable to be written nicely.

Here is a shorter proof.

If $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ counting multiplicities, then the eigenvalues of $I+tA$ are $1+t\lambda_1,\ldots,1+t\lambda_n$. Thus
$$
\det(I+tA)=(1+t\lambda_1)\cdots(1+t\lambda_n)=t^n\lambda_1\cdots\lambda_n+\cdots+t(\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_n)+1.
$$
So the coefficient of $t$ is 
$$
\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_n=\operatorname{Tr}(A). 
$$
We also see from above that the coefficient of $t^n$ is $\det A$.

Comment: Good argument! Using that trace is sum of eigenvalues and determinant is their product. But isn't it a problem involving eigenvalues when we work in a field that is not algebraically closed? Notice we live in $\mathbb R$. A real matrix could have imaginary eigenvalues. Isn't this a problem?

Comment: @OriaGruber You can think about it this way. If you have a polynomial, like $x^2 + 1$, defined over any field $k$, then you know some properties the roots must have, even though the roots might not exist in $k$. For instance, if $a, b$ are the two roots of $x^2 + 1$ then $a^2 = -1$ and $b^2 = -1$ and $b = -a$ and $ab = a(-a) = -a^2 = 1$. These properties are forced on us by the polynomial before we even know the roots exist. Likewise, the trace of $A$ is always going to be equal to the sum of the eigenvalues of $A$, even if the eigenvalues only exist in some field extension.

Comment: @Oria, Trevor already explained. the fact that the trace and the determinant also have formulas that depend only on the coefficients guarantee that they are real. So using the eigenvalues, even if they are not real, is ok.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different argument. Let the columns of $A$ be $C_i$. Then the determinant viewed as a function of the sequence of columns is multilinear.  Let $E_i$ be the columns of the identity matrix. Then you have 
$$\det(E_1+tC_1, \cdots , E_n+tC_n)$$ now by mulitlinearily this can be expanded like an binomial product, and thus the coefficient of $t$ is

$$\sum \det(E_1, \cdots , C_i,\cdots , E_n)$$  and it is easy to see that

$$ \det(E_1, \cdots , C_i,\cdots , E_n)=a_{ii}.$$